# Conan's virtualenv with CLion?

Tags: c++, clion, conan

When using CLion as an IDE with packages provided by Conan, I can't see a way to add `package/bin` to environmental variables when running an app from the IDE.
For example, the project I work with has Qt dlls as dependencies, but they are not copied to `bin` (I am not the one to change it), so when I try to run Debug, I get errors on mising Qt dlls.
A "simple" (yet ugly) way is to either copy the dlls manually or add Qt's `bin` from Conan to `PATH`. This is hardly a solution...

https://docs.conan.io/en/1.46/mastering/virtualenv.html says there's a way to add all the packages' `bin` to `PATH`. But I am failing to understand how can I do such a thing with CLion IDE.

---

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-17906 describes the issue

Comment: The CLion Conan plugin has been on hold for a while, waiting for 2.0 to be released. Now that Conan 2.0 is out, it would be good to also file a ticket in the Github repo: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-clion-plugin, and provide feedback.

Comment: @drodri Thanks, I'll look into it. For now I am running `CLion64.exe` from powershell with an actisted conan environment, like it was suggested in jetbrains ticket. That works, but IDE has to be restarted if Conan configuration changes.